# keyboard with navigation bar moves up framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, fullscreen, android-softkeyboard, samsung-galaxy

the problem occurs only when using full screen mode  (samsung galaxy s8), when keyboard is open, frame layout is forced to move up .

```
        <activity ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

and in this activity we use such hierarchy:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/actHomeBottomContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:foregroundGravity="top" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/actHomeTopContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:elevation="@dimen/grid_size"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/actHomeLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_size_8x"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/grid_size_2x"
    android:elevation="@dimen/grid_size"
    android:src="@drawable/img_tbc_logo"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

image view keeps same place, but

> actHomeTopContainer

starts moving up and down on keyboard hide/show actions. keyboard is shown from

> "actHomeBottomContainer"

also, before this we do animation - translation Y

```
   actHomeTopContainer.animate().translationY(-1 * translateYSize).start()
```

Actually I don't know how doest samsung choose the view to move up.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `adjustPan`

```
<activity ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

You can use `adjustNothing`

```
<activity ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
```

Because When you use `adjustPan`, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing.

Comment: nope. this doesn't work. android:windowSoftInputMode is just for keyboard,  but the problem is for navigation bar, not for keyboard . thanks for answer

Comment: Works for me, I just wanted the keyboard to not adjust Navigation Menu.